# How long does it take for badges to be earned?

Tags: support, badges

As of today I'm at 100 consecutive days.

How long does it take for the Fanatic badge to be earned?

Yesterday it took like 4 hours for the Electorate badge to take effect, but previously for lesser badges, It was a matter of minutes to get a badge earned, sometimes it was instant.

Is there a time that everyone needs to wait in order to receive some badges?

(inb4 we don't need no stinkin' badges)

Comment: Badges? I'd sell 'em for rep.

Comment: Was there really *any* value to [this edit](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/973/2)?

Comment: The fanatic badge may have prompted the question, but the question was about the timer in regards to all badges. Moreover, the question is five years old and has only had 60 views in that time. Do we really expect a flood of people to come in here suddenly looking for this information that it needs to be edited, or are we just looking for things to "fix"?

Comment: @phantom42 - Well, I think it’s a helpful edit (even KutuluMike put it back in after removing it), and it makes things more clear. Whether many people will see it…probably not, but meta has low traffic in any case. As to whether adding “Fanatic” is right there, note that the original said “How long does it take for *the* badge to be earned,” not “*a* badge.” So I think the referent of the second sentence is clearly the Fanatic badge.

Comment: Pointless edit if you ask me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Badges run at different frequencies.  In general, be patient for 24 hours.